# strange collision detection behavior in javascript 'game engine.'

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision-detection, game-engine

If you play with the 'game' I've set up for a moment, you'll observe that the avatar falls right through the second platform when jumping onto it. I simply cannot fathom why this is. I understand that this is probably more code than should be posted, but I'm at my wits end, and maybe someone could quickly see what I'm doing wrong.
The 'game' in question. Just use the arrow keys for run and jump.

http://jsfiddle.net/QGB69/

```
//RequestAnimationFrame shim. 

window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


//Initializing canvas and world

var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var keysDown = [];
var currentPlatform = 0;

//some helpful variables

var canvasHeight = $('#viewport').height();
var canvasWidth = $('#viewport').width();


//Add keycodes to 'keysDown' array

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.which, keysDown) === -1) {
        keysDown.push(e.keyCode);
    }
});


//Remove keycodes from 'keysDown' array

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.which, keysDown) > -1) {
        keysDown = $.grep(keysDown, function (n, i) {
            return n !== e.which;
        });
    }
});


//Avatar object, lots of attributes, great import!

var avatar = {};

avatar.xPos = 50;
avatar.yPos = 50;
avatar.accl = 0.55;
avatar.decel = 0.85;
avatar.jReduction = 1.25;
avatar.direction = null;
avatar.stopping = false;
avatar.avatarHeight = 50;
avatar.avatarWidth = 25;
avatar.fallTime = 0;
avatar.isGrounded = false;
avatar.isJumping = false;
avatar.endJump = false;
avatar.jump = 18;
avatar.j = avatar.jump;
avatar.jStrength = 0.55;
avatar.speed = 13;
avatar.prevXPos = 0;
avatar.xDelta = 0;
avatar.xVelocity = 0;
avatar.yVelocity = 0;
avatar.yBottom = 0;
avatar.xAlignment = 0;


avatar.collDetect = function (args) {

    avatar.yBottom = avatar.yPos + avatar.avatarHeight;
    avatar.xPosRight = avatar.xPos + avatar.avatarWidth;


    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (avatar.yBottom > arguments[i].boxTop) {
            if (avatar.xPos > arguments[i].xPos) {
                if (avatar.direction === 'left' && avatar.xDelta > avatar.xPos - arguments[i].xPosRight) {
                    avatar.xPos = arguments[i].xPosRight;
                    avatar.xStop();
                } else if (avatar.direction === 'left' && avatar.xPos <= arguments[i].xPosRight) {
                    avatar.xPos = arguments[i].xPosRight;
                    avatar.xStop();
                }
            } else if (avatar.xPos < arguments[i].xPos) {
                if (avatar.direction === 'right' && avatar.xDelta > arguments[i].xPos - avatar.xPosRight) {
                    avatar.xPos = arguments[i].xPos - avatar.avatarWidth;
                    avatar.xStop();
                } else if (avatar.direction === 'right' && avatar.xPos >= arguments[i].xPos) {
                    avatar.xPos = arguments[i].xPos - avatar.avatarWidth;
                    avatar.xStop();
                }
            }
        }

        if (avatar.xPos > arguments[i].xPos - avatar.avatarWidth && avatar.xPos < arguments[i].xPos + arguments[i].boxWidth) {
            currentPlatform = arguments[i].boxHeight;
        } else {
            currentPlatform = 0;
        }
    }
};

avatar.xStop = function () {
    avatar.xVelocity = 0;
    avatar.xDelta = 0;
    avatar.stopping = false;
    avatar.direction = null;
};

//First obstacle. Good luck gettin' over this one, avatar! 

function Box(xPos, boxWidth, boxHeight, boxColor) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
    this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
    this.boxColor = boxColor;
    this.xPosRight = xPos + boxWidth;
    this.boxTop = canvasHeight - boxHeight;
}

function renderBoxes(n) {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = arguments[i].boxColor;
        ctx.fillRect(arguments[i].xPos,
        canvasHeight - arguments[i].boxHeight,
        arguments[i].boxWidth,
        arguments[i].boxHeight);
    }
}

var box1 = new Box(100, 50, 100, 'gray');
var box2 = new Box(300, 50, 125, 'green');


//physics object. Properties of the world     

var physx = {};
physx.gravity = 1;
physx.colliding = false;
physx.fallTimeModifier = 0.5;


//Big movement function. The action's in here!

function moveIt() {

    //Jump!

    if ($.inArray(38, keysDown) > -1) {

        if (avatar.j > 0) {
            avatar.isGrounded = false;
            avatar.isJumping = true;
            avatar.yPos -= avatar.j;
            avatar.yVelocity = avatar.j;
            avatar.j -= avatar.jStrength;
        } else if (avatar.j <= 0) {
            avatar.isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    //End Jump, initiated when the user lets off the jump key mid-jump.

    if (avatar.endJump === true) {

        if (avatar.j > 0) {
            avatar.j -= avatar.jReduction;
            avatar.yPos -= avatar.j;
        } else if (avatar.j <= 0) {
            avatar.isJumping = false;
            avatar.endJump = false;
        }

    }

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 38 && avatar.isJumping === true) {
            avatar.endJump = true;
        }
    });

    //Accounting for deceleration when avatar stops.

    if (avatar.stopping === true) {

        if ((avatar.xVelocity - avatar.decel) <= 0) {
            avatar.xStop();
            return;
        }

        if (avatar.direction === 'right') {
            avatar.xPos += avatar.xVelocity;
            avatar.xVelocity -= avatar.decel;
            avatar.xDelta = avatar.xVelocity;
        }

        if (avatar.direction === 'left') {
            avatar.xPos -= avatar.xVelocity;
            avatar.xVelocity -= avatar.decel;
            avatar.xDelta = avatar.xVelocity
        }
    }


    //Correcting glitchy stopping behavior when conflicting left/right keycodes present in 'keysDown' array

    if ($.inArray(37, keysDown) > -1 && $.inArray(39, keysDown) > -1) {
        avatar.stopping = true;
    }

    //right

    if ($.inArray(39, keysDown) > -1) {

        if (avatar.stopping === false) {
            avatar.direction = 'right';
            if (avatar.xVelocity >= avatar.speed) {
                avatar.xPos += avatar.speed;
                avatar.xDelta = avatar.speed;
            } else {
                avatar.xPos += avatar.xVelocity;
                avatar.xVelocity += avatar.accl;
                avatar.xDelta = avatar.xVelocity;
            }
        }
    }


    //left

    if ($.inArray(37, keysDown) > -1) {

        if (avatar.stopping === false) {
            avatar.direction = 'left';
            if (avatar.xVelocity >= avatar.speed) {
                avatar.xPos -= avatar.speed;
                avatar.xDelta = avatar.speed;
            } else {
                avatar.xPos -= avatar.xVelocity;
                avatar.xVelocity += avatar.accl;
                avatar.xDeta = avatar.xVelocity;
            }
        }
    }


    //Set avatar.isStopping to true when 

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 39 || e.which === 37) {
            avatar.stopping = true;
        }
    });
}

//Gravity function. Keep him on the dang ground!

function grav() {

    if (avatar.isJumping) {
        return;
    }

    if (avatar.yPos >= (canvasHeight - currentPlatform) - avatar.avatarHeight) {
        avatar.isGrounded = true;
        avatar.fallTime = 0;
    } else {
        if ((avatar.fallTime * physx.gravity) > (((canvasHeight - currentPlatform) - avatar.avatarHeight) - avatar.yPos)) {
            avatar.yPos = (canvasHeight - currentPlatform) - avatar.avatarHeight;
            avatar.isGrounded = true;
            avatar.j = avatar.jump;
            avatar.fallTime = 0;
        } else {
            avatar.yPos += avatar.fallTime * physx.gravity;
            avatar.fallTime += physx.fallTimeModifier;
        }
    }
}


//Render the dang thing, ya dingus!

function render() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    renderBoxes(box1, box2);
    avatar.collDetect(box2, box1);
    grav();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(avatar.xPos,
    avatar.yPos,
    avatar.avatarWidth,
    avatar.avatarHeight);
    moveIt();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you almost figured this out, as I notice you've reversed the order of boxes in the collision detection call.  I'll go ahead and tell you where it is, though.

```
if (avatar.xPos > arguments[i].xPos - avatar.avatarWidth && avatar.xPos < arguments[i].xPos + arguments[i].boxWidth) {
            currentPlatform = arguments[i].boxHeight;

        } else {
            currentPlatform = 0;
        }
```

So this bit here is inside a loop.  Because you use an if / else, it will always only work for the second box.  Meaning, even if the first pass through the loop sets currentPlatform = X, the second pass will set currentPlatform = 0.

For this specific problem, try

```
if (avatar.xPos > arguments[i].xPos - avatar.avatarWidth && avatar.xPos < arguments[i].xPos + arguments[i].boxWidth) {
            currentPlatform = arguments[i].boxHeight;
            break; // <-- here

        } else {
            currentPlatform = 0;
        }
```